# Delete a created checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following HTML file:

```
<div class="tituloD">
</div>
<div class="subtituloD">
</div>
<div class="puntosD">
</div>
```

I have this JQuery javascript:

```
// Esta funcion recoge el json data de puntos importantes y lo imprime en pantalla  
function resultsPuntos(data) { 

    //Si el punto no se ha creado antes, se crea la estructura
    if(puntosCreados == "No"){
        $("div.puntosD").append("Puntos importantes: ");
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
        puntosCreados = "Si";
    }
    else{
        //Vaciar estructura
        $("#checkbox").replaceWith('');

        //Crear estructura de nuevo
        $.each(data,function(index,value) {
            $("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to display a checkbox with the options comming from a database. For that I detect if it's the first time it's being created (`if(puntosCreados == "No")`), if so I write the checkbox structure. If it is not, I try emptying the checkbox structure first (`$("#checkbox").replaceWith('');`), however, this is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have an element with id="checkbox"? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any checkbox with the ID 'checkbox'? I think what you mean is:

```
// remove all checkboxes
$("input[type='checkbox']").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! This removes the checkboxes, however, it doesn't remove the labels. I tried this but it didn't work...
$("input[type='checkbox']").next('label').remove();

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just removing it ??

```
$("#checkbox").remove();
```

Also, the appended checkbox does not seem to have an ID.

Comment: I tried putting this code now for the checkboxes (added the "id" field "puntoscheck"):

$("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" name="'+data[index].id+'" id="puntoscheck" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);

Now I try removing it using:
$("#puntoscheck").remove();

However, it doesn't work...